# Enable SSO for user authentication in django python project using keycloak as identity broker

Tags: python, django, keycloak

I am trying to enable SSO using keycloak as identity broker and Microsoft AD as identity provider(where keycloak will delegate the client's authentication request to AD) in a django python project.

Tech stack of application:
frontend- React,
backend - django python

For this I am using python-keycloak library in django to communicate with keycloak.What I am able to achieve is : setup a connection with keycloak and get access_token and refresh_token when username and password is provided like this:

```py
        # Create Keycloak instance
        self.keycloak = KeycloakOpenID(server_url=self.server_url,
                                       client_id=self.client_id,
                                       realm_name=self.realm,
                                       client_secret_key=self.client_secret_key)

        # Get WellKnow
        self.config_well_know = self.keycloak.well_know()

        # Get Token
        self.token = self.keycloak.token("user","pwd")

        # get userinfo
        self.userInfo = self.keycloak.userinfo(self.token['access_token'])
        # userinfo returned ok
```

But here i am providing username and password which I should not as I want to enable sso with Microsoft AD(Note: keycloak realm is configured to use Microsoft AD as default IDP) and only username should be sufficient to enable SSO with Microsoft. But it is giving error on passing only username.

Question:
How to authenticate user from Microsoft AD using keycloak broker and what should be the syntax for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Create two clients in your example realm. One for your React app, setup as Public client where you should use Javascript adapter to generate access token where u pass that using headers and your backend Django app setup as a confidential client that could access the access token generated from the fronted react app. Using python-keycloak Library do introspect the token for its correctness.

Try setting up Identity brokering in your example realm using OIDC/SAML use your Azure apps metadata URL to set up the profile along with relevant mappers.

After this setup you should get SSO to work properly.